Find the chromatic polynomial of a graph using deletion and contraction
Find the chromatic polynomial of the following graph.
The graph in question is the one on top and I am doing deletion and contraction recursively as the picture shows.

This is what I get and I have no clue whether I have done it correctly or not. I am using deletion and contraction algorithms and but I am getting wrong answer. Correct answer is $k(k − 1)(k − 2)^2(k^2 − 5k + 8)$

You've done the deletion-contraction correctly, but your chromatic polynomials for all four graphs you get at the end are wrong. All of them can be solved in the same way, which I'll illustrate on the leftmost graph.
There are two cases:

The top and bottom vertex could be the same color. In that case, there's $k$ possibilities for that color, and $(k-1)^4$ ways to color the $4$ remaining vertices, because all they need to do is not be that color.
The top and bottom vertex could be different colors. In that case, there's $k(k-1)$ possibilities for their colors, and $(k-2)^4$ ways to color the $4$ remaining vertices, because they cannot be either color.

Altogether, the chromatic polynomial of that graph is $k(k-1)^4 + k(k-1)(k-2)^4$, not the $k^2(k-1)^4$ you have.

How comde it isn't k^2 possiblities for up and bottom vertices in scenario one in your solution?

@Need_MathHelp In that scenario, we're assuming that they're the same color, so there's only one $k$-way choice to be made, not two. Once you choose the color of the top vertex (in $k$ ways) you don't have any choices left to make for the bottom vertex.
